# How to do a Fisher's exact $2 \times 2$ test on data over MANY randomized trials?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, contingency-tables, fishers-exact-test

Suppose that we have several randomized trials over two treatment options for cancer, and we take note if cancer recurred after taking the drug or not. As a clear-cut example, I have included a sample dataset with 14 randomized trials over cancer treatment of Tamoxifen and a Control:

[image: DATA]

For each study, Rec. means if it recurred or not. My question is, could we combine the entire data into a Fisher's exact 2x2 test? In other words, let us sum the first column, then take the second column, sum it, then subtract from the first's sum, to get:

```
               Recurrence  No Recurrence  
    Tamoxifen  1989        2554  
    Control    2256        2329
```

Would a Fisher's exact test off this table be valid? thanks!

Comment: Short answer: normally not

Comment: You might like to look at some of the resources in the meta-analysis tag wiki http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/meta-analysis/info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Besides needing time-to-event analysis as mentioned by Bjorn, note that Fisher's "exact" test is not very accurate and should be replaced by the ordinary Pearson $\chi^2$ test if $Y$ is truly binary.

Comment: To add to this: the Exact test is not accurate in the sense that it is a conservative test, meaning that a test of the 0.05 level will have an effective size of less than 0.05, and you lose power compared to the Chi-sq test.

Answer (score 4):

What you would normally want to do in this kind of situation is a meta-analysis of some form. The closest equivalent to Fischer's exact test would be to use exact logistic regression stratified by trial.

But is this really a binomial outcome? I would assume the individual trials might have been more appropriately analyzed using time-to-event methods and it is likely better to combine the results of such analyses rather than artficially turning it into a binomial data problem, which it isn't.

Comment: Since the total number of entries is near $10,000$ would Fisher's exact test break down here or is it still debated what the cutoff is?

Comment: I would like to just do a Fisher's exact test, what is a valid way to use the data so that a Fisher's exact test would be valid?

Comment: In this kind of situation a naive pooling (i.e. summing up the columns) is inappropriate unless the expected proportion with an event is the same in  the same arm of each trial. As soon as follow up length of patient severity differs a bit this is typically not the case.

Comment: @user321627 Fisher's exact test is not a solution for small sample sizes. FET handles 0 cell-counts (which may arise in large sample sizes), but so do score tests for that matter. You are far from such an issue here. You can *do* a FET in this case but your rationale is incorrect.

Comment: @Björn if there is no censoring, and the outcome of interest is binary even when it relates to survival (say 5 year survival or more), then I think analyses other than time-to-event could be appropriate. Also the logistic regression with fixed effects for trial is a good suggestion, the Mantel Haenszel OR also happens to be the score test for such a model. (+1) if you can provide methods for aggregating trial data in a survival analysis. This is interesting to me. Is fixed effects for trials appropriate as with the logistic model?

Comment: @AdamO You are right that analyses such as LR with trial effect, stratified by trial etc., MH OR etc. would be a more appropriate form of a binomial data analysis than a FET. However, with this number of trials and patients, there will have been losses to follow-up. Also note that by a constant OR over trials of different duration assumes that the hazard ratio changes over time (may be true, but...). Plus you throw away the information in the timing of the events (mostly an issue if more than, say, 10 to 15% of patients per trial have an event), a reported hazard ratio would have used that.

Comment: @Björn absolutely, and I appreciate practical answers that encourage the OP to think a bit more deeply about the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this. The Fisher test is a test of 2 by 2 data, asymptotically consistent with the OR and corresponding Pearson chi-sq test. Using either of these tests would be wrong because you would be pooling data. So I'll describe exactly why you can't pool these data. Basically, it's because of collapsibility of the OR.

The reason why your approach is not okay is because you are not comparing cases to controls in their respective studies. For instance, suppose inclusion criteria in trial 1 is to have stage 4 disease so that risk of recurrence (or death) is very high. However, suppose inclusion criteria in trial 2 is to have stage 3 or 4 disease so that risk is slightly lower. Even when the odds ratio is constant between the studies (it's usually not), the pooled data will not yield the same results.

As a simple example:

Trial 1 has 10 treated (5 of whom fail) and 10 untreated (7 of whom fail) for an OR of 5 * 3 / (5 * 7) = 3/7. Trial 2 also has 10 treated (3 of whom fail) and 14 untreated (7 of whom fail) for an OR of 3 * 7 / (7 * 7) = 3/7. The pooled OR is given by 8 * 10 / (12 * 14) = 10 / 21. In this case 10/21 > 3/7 which means the effect of intervention is *attenuated*. This is a general problem with collabsibility: strata specific ORs are stronger than their crude counterparts. This is why you don't collapse them.

A simple way of obtaining a stratified odds ratio for the various studies is to calculate the [Mantel Haenszel odds ratio](http://www.statsdirect.com/help/meta_analysis/mh.htm).

This statistic calculates a pooled OR of (5*3/20 + 3*7/24)/(5*7/20 + 7*7/24) = 3/7

This problem persists even in seemingly identical studies with the same inclusion criteria because of heterogeneity between studies. Use a stratified estimator.